# Google geocoding viewports

Tags: google-maps

Does the viewports in the Google geocoding represents the boundary boxes of the location ?  Iam trying to use google viewports of particular city or location to search for the latitude and longitude values that fall in those bounding values.
I have two tables called tblproperty and tblemailalerts, tblproperty has got latitude and longitude values and tblemailalerts also got viewport + latitude and longitude values . Now I want to get the sql to get the matching records with accuracy

I want to achieve similar to zoopla search 
for example when user selects location as london , properties should be shown within the boundaries of london. If they select london within 1/4 mile radius i should get the properties within the london + properties with 1/4 radius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The viewport `bounds` parameter only biases the results. It's not a hard limit. You can read about viewport biasing in the [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Viewports).

However, the viewport returned by Google for a query for "London" does represent a bounding box you can use in your SQL query.

You could also use the OpenStreetMap API. The query to get a bounding box for London is:

http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=London&format=json

In there you will find a number of bounding boxes for places called "London" around the world, but the first one is London, United Kingdom.

Comment: Hi ,You mean viewports are not bounding boxes , then please suggest me what is the best way of getting boundary boxes of locations to get search results .

Comment: You can't using the API, but you can use viewport biasing and then filter your results to keep only those in the bounding box.

Comment: Hiii , I want to do it in the sql query  as i store the  user given location  values from API into database table to compare it with table which contains properties and send email alerts

Comment: Yep, that sounds like it will work. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE lat BETWEEN min_lat AND max_lat AND lng BETWEEN min_lng AND max_lng;` Radius is a little harder. You'll need to calculate sqrt(delta lat + delta lng).

Comment: hii, what do you mean by min and max , are they viewports ?  As I said earlier I want all the properties in london when user gives input as london .

Comment: Exactly. They're the upper and lower bounds of your bounding box.

Comment: hii, what do you mean by min and max , are they viewports ?  As I said earlier I want all the properties in london when user gives input as london(need boundaries of london so i used viewports) .If user says london within 1/4 or any other it should show locations within london +radius

Comment: So what part are you having a problem with? What have you done so far? This isn't a code writing service, it's to help solve specific problems you're having with your code.

Comment: I would like to expalin you my methodology , correct me if iam wrong . My ultimate aim is to send the email alerts to the people with given inputs.I have taken the viewports of given location and stored in the table called emailalerts. Now I would like to compare those with the latitude and longitude values in the tblproperty . My question is am i going in the right path to achieve the accurate results if not what is the best way to do it

Comment: The answer to the main question you've asked is "no". To get more you need to either edit the question, or ask a new one. Comments aren't for working this stuff out. You might want to take a look at [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you frame your improved question.

Comment: I took the viewpoints as bounding boxes because for example london has got only one latitude and longitude value so to get the accurate values I took the viewports from API